# Saving WMA in NAudio

Tags: c#, wav, naudio, wma

I'm trying to convert a WAV file into a WMA file using NAudio. I've managed to get it partly working but the last few seconds of the sound effect is cut off.

```
WaveFileReader wr = new WaveFileReader(@"C:\mywav.wav");
WmaWriter ww = new WmaWriter(new FileStream(@"C:\mywma.wma",FileMode.Create),new WaveFormat(44100,2),profile);

byte[] buff = null;

int read = 0;

buff=new byte[wr.Length];
read = wr.Read(buff,0,buff.Length);
while ((read > 0))
{
  ww.Write(buff,0,read);
  read = wr.Read(buff,0,buff.Length);
}
```

This only partly writes a WMA file and not the whole WAV file that's read in. Alternatively is there a way to convert to WMA without the need for NAudio in C#?

Comment: There is a chance this is related to buffering and not disposing properly. If `WmaWriter` allows it, add a `Flush()` and `Close()` at the end. Alternatively, use a `using` block around the writer to ensure it's disposed correctly. You may need both.

Comment: I've been working all day on this and it was the 'using' block that was needed. Thanks very much! Please post it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, use a `using` block with the writer (and reader actually) so the streams are flushed and closed properly.